# Magento2 design fallback logic

Tags: magento2, theme, design, theme-fallback

We already know design fallback logic from Magento 1.x:

1. Current package / Current Theme
2. Current Package / Default theme
3. Base Package / Default theme

Now. i want to know What is the design fallback logic in Magento 2.x for theme, layout & template files?

Please describe briefly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The point is, compared to Magento 1, where a pseudo fallback mechanism was implemented. **Magento 2 has a mechanism that falls back as many times as a parent theme can be found**. The system is very similar to the one introduced on Magento 1.9 using `theme.xml` files.

For instance, when you have 5 themes inheriting from each other, then the mechanism will fall back to each one of them. The package is not taken into consideration anymore.

Here is a pseudo code that can describe the new design mechanisme:

```
do
    look in the current theme
    current theme will be parent theme on the next iteration
while the current theme has a parent theme

look in the view folder of the module area if the layout/template is not defined in the previous steps
```

As an example of static file fallback, suppose there is a request for the `logo.svg` image in the Blank theme.

Using theme inheritance and view file fallback rules, Magento uses the following search order:

1. `app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/images/logo.svg`
2. `app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/web/logo.svg`
3. `app/design/frontend/Magento/parent_theme/web/images/logo.svg`
4. `app/design/frontend/Magento/parent_theme/web/logo.svg`

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/view/static-process.html

Comment: nice share @Raphel.What about layout &template?

Comment: @AmitBera I've edited my answer as the example provided was kind of confusing in the first part of my answer.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism The reference link provided gives 404, it would also be great if you can include design fallback on modules.

Answer (score 1):

Current fallback logic of theme:

1. **`Current_theme/<Namespace>_<Module>/`**
2. **`parent_theme(s)/<Namespace>_<Module>/`**
3. **`module_dir/view/frontend/`**
4. **`module_dir/view/base/`**

This pattern has used for layout and template also.

Answer (score 0):

The fallback logic in Magento 2 is completely different from Magento 1, and associated with the theme inheritance feature.

According to the document:

> The fallback order is slightly different for static assets (CSS, JavaScript, fonts and images) and other theme files, layouts and templates.

You can check more details in the document via this link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-inherit.html