# Magento 2: Layout override sequence custom theme vs extensions

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, theme, overrides

I created a **custom storefront theme** and override the `catalog_product_view.xml` file in my custom theme. Below is the path.

```
app\design\frontend\Akhilg\custom\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml
```

It's working as expected.

Now let's say I have downloaded a third party extension **(EXTENSION1)** which using set template for the reference `product.info.addtocart` in the same layout file i.e `catalog_product_view.xml`. like below

```
<action method="setTemplate">
    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendername_Modulename::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
</action>
```

also uses sequence definition in their `module.xml`

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
</sequence>
```

Now let's say there is one more third party extension **(EXTENSION2)** doing the same.

I have two questions

**1. How Magento decide priority between Custom Theme, Extension1 Extension2**.

Is there any naming convention?

**1. How I make all functionality(Changes in custom theme, Extension1 and Extension2) works together.**

Do I need to make a single file and merge all changes in one file?

Answer (score 1):

**Layout Merging Order**

1. Magento first merges layout files into the module's base area
2. The request area module files are loaded (frontend or adminhtml).
   Above two are depend upon [Module's load order](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html), it can be controlled using `sequence` tag in `module.xml` and module's load order can be seen in `app/etc/config.php`
3. Layout files in theme are loaded (current theme first and then the parent theme).

**How I make all functionality(Changes in custom theme, Extension1 and Extension2) works together.**

You need not to worry about merging because Magento does it as mentioned above. You just need to follow the order.
If you are customizing the same node/tag at multiple places then the last loaded will take the precedence and works.

**References:**

- https://belvg.com/blog/magento-2-certification-layout-merging-overview.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 2** Fall back logic:

```
current_theme/{Namespace_Module}/
parent_theme/{Namespace_Module}/
module_dir/view/frontend/
module_dir/view/base/
```

Source : [@Amit Bera](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109308/magento2-design-fallback-logic)

You hanven't to merge the layout files in one, Magento do it for you, it Merge all layout files into one `xml` file.